# Join using hasMany (first row) and then it's hasOne

Tags: laravel, join, query-builder

I have 3 tables. `transactions`, `packages` and `package_activities`.

- Transaction hasMany Packages (using `transactions_id` => `packages.transaction_id`).
- Package has one Activity (using `packages.tracking_number` => `package_activites.tracking_number`)

```
transactions: id 

packages: id | transaction_id | tracking_number

package_activities: id | tracking_number | last_activity_at
```

I am trying to join from transactions so that it **transaction's first package's activities's last_activity_at**.

---

If in Packages `transaction_id` exists only one time, this works:

```
Transaction::query()
    ->join('packages', 'transactions.id', '=', 'packages.transaction_id')
```

But for multiple, i couldn't join with only one, so it crashes with error

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

---

So I think I need to do something like this but I couldn't make it work.

```
Transaction::query()
  ->leftJoin('packages', function ($join) {
       $join->on('packages.id', '=', \DB::raw('(SELECT min(`id`) FROM packages'));
  })
```

---

The ultimate goal is returning only `last_activity_at` of the first package of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

> `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous`

This means that in your query, it's not clear if `id` means `transactions.id`, `packages.id` or `package_activities.id`.

Be more explicit.

```php
Transaction::query()
  ->leftJoin('packages', function ($join) {
       $join->on('packages.id', '=', \DB::raw('(SELECT min(`packages.id`) FROM packages'));
  })
```